# Cantidad de dígitos indeterminados y opcionales en Regex

Tags: regex

Estoy intentando montar una expresión regular que me permita aceptar una X cantidad de carácteres pero que al mismo tiempo sean opcionales.

De momento lo que tengo es esto.

`^x_PREFIJO-[0]+CODIGO-`

Lo que me valida entradas como: `x_PREFIJO-00CODIGO-blah-blah-blah`

Pero no me permite: `x_PREFIJO-CODIGO-blah-blah-blah`

He probado con `^x_PREFIJO-[[0]+]?CODIGO-`, `^x_PREFIJO-[0]+?CODIGO-` y algunas similares, pero no sé como englobar la parte del `[0]+` para que sea opcional.

Comment: Prueba con este patrón `^x_PREFIJO-0*+CODIGO-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que quiere es

```
x_PREFIJO-[0-9]*CODIGO-
```

El * significa 0 veces o más.

Comment: Justo lo había encontrado, pero gracias era lo que buscaba :)